# Can't connect to port, although it is open

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, port, firewall

I set up a raspi with Windows 10 IoT.

I then put up a firewall rule on the raspi to open port 1600 like so:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 1600" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1600
```

The command `netstat -an` displays the following:

```
 TCP    10.3.10.200:1600       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

But when i run the command `Test-NetConnection -Port 1600 "ComputerName"`  (on a computer in the same subnet) i get

```
WARNING: TCP connect to (fe80::4d23:cb14:dcf6:dc5b%9 : 1600) failed


ComputerName     : ComputerName
RemoteAddress    : 10.3.10.200
RemotePort       : 1600
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 10.3.10.69
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

I can ping the raspi without problems. I can also connect to port 8080 without any problems.
Any ideas why the connection to port 1600 fails?

Comment: Client tries to connect to IPv6 address fe80::4d23:cb14:dcf6:dc5b. Maybe your server is listening only IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SKi suggested, the problem may come from trying to connect to an IPv6 address instead of the IPv4 address that you are listening to. Instead, you can try entering the IPv4 address, `10.3.10.200`, as the "ComputerName" to restrict the test to IPv4.